# Maximum Recursion Error with Selenium's driver.get() call

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

I am using selenium to running automated scripts in Python. I have used the tool for three years, but have never encountered this issue. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I was able to determine that the cause of the error was the reference to `driver.get()` inside a for loop, but it errors out after 7 iterations. Seems odds, thoughts?

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function crawl_games_and_store_data.<locals>.handle_incoming_request at 0x104659158>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/z003bzf/Documents/personal/python/MLB/src/services/crawler.py", line 160, in handle_incoming_request
    driver.get(game_link)
  File "/Users/z003bzf/.local/share/virtualenvs/MLB-Ei2Ym8vD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/z003bzf/.local/share/virtualenvs/MLB-Ei2Ym8vD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
    params = self._wrap_value(params)
  File "/Users/z003bzf/.local/share/virtualenvs/MLB-Ei2Ym8vD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 271, in _wrap_value
    converted[key] = self._wrap_value(val)
  File "/Users/z003bzf/.local/share/virtualenvs/MLB-Ei2Ym8vD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 276, in _wrap_value
    return list(self._wrap_value(item) for item in value)
```

---

Here is the code that is causing the issue

```
for elem in link_lst:
     driver.get(elem)
     time.sleep(.5)

     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="box-row batting-row"]')
```

Comment: Post the actual code where the issue is... as in a [mcve].

Comment: I added my code below as an answer, since comments does not support code syntaxing.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code and any other relevant details there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the contents of link_lst, if there's a timeout on one of the hosts.  You would have to handle this exception to continue forward. One possible option would be to use a try/except on a timeout as well as not being able to locate a page element. This can be adjusted both as a delay parameter, but also in the firefox profile settings.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def fetch(driver, link_list, delay)
    for item in link_list:
        try:
            driver.get(item)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Timeout in link_list item")

        try:
            elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 
            delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH '//div[@class="box-row batting-row"]')))
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Locating element took too much time!")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    """ Setup profile """
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 10)
    fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 10)

    """ Prepare args """
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
    link_list = ['http://abcdeftest.com', 'http://test.com']
    delay = 5

    fetch(driver, link_list, delay)
```